# Close hover submenu after click without page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I have a nav menu system with submenus like the example below. On the submenu (revealed by hovering over "Two-Level") is the option "Do AJAX Only". If that option is selected, an ajax routine will run and I want the dropdown menu to immediately hide itself again (that is, as soon as the option is clicked the submenu should disappear).

I tried jQuery `hide()`, but that permanently disables the submenu *(i.e. sliding the mouse back to the menu bar does not reveal it again)*.

I also tried `hide()` and then `show()`, but that makes the submenu stay visible even after moving the mouse away.

`mouseleave()` and `mouseout()` sounded promising, but neither seems to do anything, no matter what related element I apply them to.

Here is the simplified code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.ajax').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //to keep from jumping to top of page
    //$(this).closest('ul').hide(); /* this breaks the menu */
    /* none of these do anything I can see */
    $(this).mouseleave();
    $(this).parent().mouseleave();
    $(this).parent().parent().mouseleave();
    $(this).trigger("mouseout");
    $(this).parent().trigger("mouseout");
    $(this).parent().parent().trigger("mouseout");
    $(this).trigger("mouseleave");
    $(this).parent().trigger("mouseleave");
    $(this).parent().parent().trigger("mouseleave");

    /* do stuff with AJAX */
  });
});
```

```css
ul.nav {
  background-color:rgb(88,57,7);
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 30px;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}
ul.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
ul.nav-sub { /* second level menus */
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color:rgb(88,57,7);
  margin: -4px 0 0 15px;
  border: 1px solid LightSteelBlue;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 0;
}
ul.nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  z-index:100;
}
ul.nav-sub li {
  display: block;
}
ul.nav a {
  display: block;
  color: LightSteelBlue;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
ul.nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(132,78,12);
  color: White;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="file1.php" target="_top">Simple</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Two-level &#x25BC;</a>
    <ul class="nav-sub">
      <li><a href="file2.php" target="_top">Go to a page</a></li>
      <li><a class="ajax" href="#">Do AJAX only</a></li>
      <li><a href="file3.php">Go to another page</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/OsakaWebbie/pen/yWLXeV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to credit myself with the answer, but I had to do significant more research after Golda's answer before I got something that would work for me, and my solution might be useful for others who read this later. My real menu has multiples of all the types of elements, and even the whole nav menu markup is duplicated, so I can't use IDs. Other than the general inference that it would be necessary to replace CSS's `hover` pseudo-element functionality with JS, I didn't end up using Golda's code.

Things I learned:

- `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` are better events for this than `mouseover` and `mouseout`, because `mouseover` and `mouseout` keep firing in a hot mess when the mouse moves between items on the submenu (and even sometimes not firing if I move too fast!). [Golda's answer did work with `mouseover/mouseout` as long as they were caught on two elements per submenu and IDs were assigned to everything. I tried for hours to find the right jQuery selectors to do the same thing with DOM heirarchy and classes, to no avail.]
- An excellent explanation of the difference between `mouseover/mouseout` and `mouseenter/mouseleave` is at: https://javascript.info/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave
- I learned about the optional second argument for jQuery selectors: context. `$("ul",this)` means the `ul` descendant(s) of `$(this)`, which worked perfectly for this.

So the solution is to go up a level to the `<li>` parent of the submenu, and catch `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` there. This ends up with far less special markup, so future modifications to the menu structure are less likely to have bugs from a misplaced class or two. The only additional class I needed was `class="hassub"` on the top `<li>`. In fact, I don't even reference the class "nav-sub" in the jQuery - I only still need it for CSS. I originally thought I would only apply the jQuery to submenus that have AJAX links (because CSS `hover` was working fine without it), but it's simpler to let the jQuery operate on all submenus, so the CSS `ul.nav li:hover ul { display: block; }` is no longer needed.  Here is the code, with the markup expanded to be a little more realistic:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".hassub").mouseenter(function() { $("ul",this).show(); });
  $(".hassub").mouseleave(function() { $("ul",this).hide(); });
  
  $('.ajaxlink').click(function() { $(this).closest('ul').hide(); });
});
```

```css
ul.nav {
  background-color:rgb(88,57,7);
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 30px;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}
ul.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
ul.nav-sub {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color:rgb(88,57,7);
  margin: -4px 0 0 15px;
  border: 1px solid LightSteelBlue;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 0;
  z-index:100;
}
ul.nav-sub li {
  display: block;
}
ul.nav a {
  display: block;
  color: LightSteelBlue;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
ul.nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(132,78,12);
  color: White;
}
/*ul.nav li:hover ul {
display: block;
}*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="file1.php">solo page</a></li>
  <li class="hassub">
    <a href="#">submenu1 (mixed) &#x25BC;</a>
    <ul class="nav-sub">
      <li><a href="file2.php">page 1a</a></li>
      <li><a href="file3.php">page 1b</a></li>
      <li><a class="ajaxlink" href="#">ajax 1-1</a></li>
      <li><a href="file2.php">page 1c</a></li>
      <li><a href="file3.php">page 1d</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="hassub">
    <a href="#">submenu2 (only pages) &#x25BC;</a>
    <ul class="nav-sub">
      <li><a href="file2.php">page 2a</a></li>
      <li><a href="file3.php">page 2b</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="hassub3" class="hassub">
    <a href="#">submenu3 (only ajax) &#x25BC;</a>
    <ul id="sub3" class="nav-sub">
      <li><a class="ajaxlink" href="#">ajax 3-1</a></li>
      <li><a class="ajaxlink" href="#">ajax 3-2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following answer will help you. I have set ID's to menu link, submenu and Do AJAX link. I have shown the menu using moveover event and hide it using mouseout event

```js
$(function() {
$("#twoLink, #subMenu").mouseover(function(){
 $("#subMenu").show();
});

$("#twoLink, #subMenu").mouseout(function(){
 $("#subMenu").hide();
});

 $("#doAjaxLink").click(function(){
    $("#subMenu").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
ul.nav {
  background-color:rgb(88,57,7);
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 30px;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}
ul.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
ul.nav-sub { /* second level menus */
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color:rgb(88,57,7);
  margin: -4px 0 0 15px;
  border: 1px solid LightSteelBlue;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 0;
}
ul.nav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  z-index:100;
}
ul.nav-sub li {
  display: block;
}
ul.nav a {
  display: block;
  color: LightSteelBlue;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
ul.nav a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(132,78,12);
  color: White;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="file1.php" target="_top">Simple</a></li>
  <li>
    <a id="twoLink" href="#">Two-level &#x25BC;</a>
    <ul id="subMenu" class="nav-sub">
      <li><a href="file2.php" target="_top">Go to a page</a></li>
      <li><a id="doAjaxLink" class="ajax" href="#">Do AJAX only</a></li>
      <li><a href="file3.php">Go to another page</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I can't use IDs - not only do I have multiples of all the types of things, but I duplicate the whole menu markup in a second container for mobile (I know I should come up with a better method, but that's a battle for a later time). But I see your point: You don't see any way to use the actual CSS hover action, so you show and hide manually. Is the hover CSS even necessary if I get your idea to work in my real code? I'm currently trying to implement it using the DOM hierarchy and classes, but I'm having trouble getting the selectors right - I'll keep trying.